# What career slots count as dedicated?

Tags: character-creation, wfrp-3e

Player's Guide, p. 37-38 states:

> Each career has several talent slots along the side of its sheet, showing the different affinities or knacks for that career.
>
> Some careers have one of these slots reserved for a special talent specific to that career. For example, wizard characters have a slot devoted to their Order of Magic, while priest characters have a slot dedicated to the god they serve. Players who have a character with a dedicated talent slot should find the corresponding card and place
> it next to the career sheet. Acquiring the card for a dedicated talent slot does not cost any creation points.
> Players without a special dedicated talent slot may be able to begin play with one or more talents depending on how many creation points the player invests. The player may choose cards from any of the talent types available, but will only be able to use the abilities on talent cards that match the slots available on his character’s career card.

How should one know if one of career slots is a dedicated slot? Slots are just listed for each career, and there is no mention if one of them is dedicated in any basic career included in the Guide (p. 142-164). Neither wizard, nor priest (careers mentioned in the above quotation) explain, which of their slots are dedicated and which are not. Does it depend on **Special** section of the career description?

I'm trying to figure out, which talents (or talent groups) can be acquired for free during the character creation process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Some careers have **one of these slots reserved for a special talent
>   specific to that career**. For example, wizard characters have a slot
>   devoted to their Order of Magic, while priest characters have a slot
>   dedicated to the god they serve.

Looks like the examples clause here is somewhat misleading, since that is pretty much an exhaustive list of possible special talent kinds.

Please notice the "Appendix Three: Talents & Specialties" (p.177 - p.181). Talents there are broken into six categories, two of which, Orders and Faiths, are having a distinct "Specialty:" prefix.

> Some talents are extremely specific, and relate to a particular career
>   or role. For example, a wizard’s College of Magic or a priest’s chosen deity are examples of two very **specific talents called Specialty talents** — they help further define part of a character’s makeup.

So whenever your career calls for an Order or Faith Talent, you can get one for free at the beginning.

It's actually can be traced through Basic careers that call for one of the two Talent types: Apprentice Wizard (p.143) and Initiate (p. 151), which both have the 'Special' clause requiring them to choose a College or a Deity when starting the career.

Comment: And yes, a sixth Talent category is for the animal companion.